# Two geom_points add a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

I plot a 2 geom_point graph with the following code:

```
source("http://www.openintro.org/stat/data/arbuthnot.R")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = year,y = boys),data=arbuthnot,colour = '#3399ff') +
  geom_point(aes(x = year,y = girls),data=arbuthnot,shape = 17,colour = '#ff00ff') +
  xlab(label = 'Year') +
  ylab(label = 'Rate')
```

I simply want to know how to add a legend on the right side. With the same shape and color. Triangle pink should have the legend "woman" and blue circle the legend "men". Seems quite simple but after many trial I could not do it. (I'm a beginner with ggplot).

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you rename your columns of the original data frame and then melt it into long format with`reshape2::melt`, it's much easier to handle in ggplot2. By specifying the `color` and `shape` aesthetics in the ggplot command, and specifying the scales for the colors and shapes manually, the legend will appear.

```
source("http://www.openintro.org/stat/data/arbuthnot.R")
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

names(arbuthnot) <- c("Year", "Men", "Women")

arbuthnot.melt <- melt(arbuthnot, id.vars = 'Year', variable.name = 'Sex', 
    value.name = 'Rate')

ggplot(arbuthnot.melt, aes(x = Year, y = Rate, shape = Sex, color = Sex))+
geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values = c("Women" = '#ff00ff','Men' = '#3399ff')) + 
scale_shape_manual(values = c('Women' = 17, 'Men' = 16))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks is exactly what I was looking for. The structure seems to be slightly more difficult to get than using only ggplot2. I will have a look at reshape2 documentation... Thank you

Answer (score 15):

This is the trick that I usually use. Add `colour` argument to the `aes` and use it as an indicator for the label names.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = year,y = boys, colour = 'Boys'),data=arbuthnot) +
  geom_point(aes(x = year,y = girls, colour = 'Girls'),data=arbuthnot,shape = 17) +
  xlab(label = 'Year') +
  ylab(label = 'Rate')
```

[image]

Comment: good idea :-), any idea how then to specify the color for that? I'm also using a brewer palette in another `geom_point`

Comment: scale_colour_discrete <- function(...) {
  scale_colour_manual(..., values = c("red","yellow","green"))
}

Answer (score 9):

Here is a way of doing this without using reshape::melt.  reshape::melt works, but you can get into a bind if you want to add other things to the graph, such as line segments.  The code below uses the original organization of data.  The key to modifying the legend is to make sure the arguments to scale_color_manual(...) and scale_shape_manual(...) are identical otherwise you will get two legends.

```
source("http://www.openintro.org/stat/data/arbuthnot.R")
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)



ptheme <- theme (
  axis.text            = element_text(size = 9),              # tick labels
  axis.title           = element_text(size = 9),              # axis labels
  axis.ticks           = element_line(colour = "grey70", size = 0.25),
  panel.background     = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA),
  panel.border         = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "grey70", size = 0.25),
  panel.grid.major     = element_line(colour = "grey85", size = 0.25),
  panel.grid.minor     = element_line(colour = "grey93", size = 0.125),
  panel.margin         = unit(0 , "lines"),
  legend.justification = c(1, 0), 
  legend.position      = c(1, 0.1),
  legend.text          = element_text(size = 8),
  plot.margin          = unit(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01), "npc")   # c(bottom, left, top, right), values can be negative
)

cols    <- c( "c1" = "#ff00ff", "c2" = "#3399ff" )
shapes  <- c("s1" = 16, "s2" = 17)

p1 <- ggplot(data = arbuthnot, aes(x = year))
p1 <- p1 + geom_point(aes( y = boys,  color = "c1", shape = "s1"))
p1 <- p1 + geom_point(aes( y = girls, color = "c2", shape = "s2")) 
p1 <- p1 + labs( x = "Year", y = "Rate" )
p1 <- p1 + scale_color_manual(name = "Sex", 
                                breaks = c("c1", "c2"), 
                                values = cols,
                                labels = c("boys", "girls"))
p1 <- p1 + scale_shape_manual(name = "Sex", 
                              breaks = c("s1", "s2"),
                              values = shapes,
                              labels = c("boys", "girls"))
p1 <- p1 +  ptheme

print(p1)
```

[output results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Wna.png)

Comment: This code will get messy pretty quickly if we have, for example, 5-6+ categories of fruit, instead of "boys" and "girls".

Comment: Great work you save me some time. Thank you Ken Junk

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer based on the `tidyverse` package. Where one can use the pipe, `%>%`, to chain functions together. Creating the plot in one continues manner, omitting the need to create temporarily variables. More on the pipe can be found in this post [What does %>% function mean in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125672/what-does-function-mean-in-r)

As far as I know, legends in ggplot2 are only based on aesthetic variables. So to add a discrete legend one uses a category column, and change the aesthetics according to the category. In ggplot this is for example done by `aes(color=category)`.

So to add two (or more) different variables of a data frame to the legends, one needs to transform the data frame such that we have a category column telling us which column (variable) is being plotted, and a second column that actually holds the value. The `tidyr::gather` function, that was also loaded by `tidyverse`, does exactly that.

Then one creates the legend by just specifying which aesthetics variables need to be different. In this example the code would look as follows:

```
source("http://www.openintro.org/stat/data/arbuthnot.R")
library(tidyverse)

arbuthnot %>%
    rename(Year=year,Men=boys,Women=girls) %>%
    gather(Men,Women,key = "Sex",value = "Rate") %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(x = Year, y=Rate, color=Sex, shape=Sex)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Men" = "#3399ff","Women"= "#ff00ff")) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c("Men" = 16, "Women" =  17))
```

Notice that `tidyverse` package also automatically loads in the `ggplot2` package. An overview of the packages installed can be found on their website [tidyverse.org](https://www.tidyverse.org/).

In the code above I also used the function `dplyr::rename` (also loaded by `tidyverse`) to first rename the columns to the wanted labels. Since the legend automatically takes the labels equal to the category names.

There is a second way to renaming labels of legend, which involves specifying the labels explicitly in the `scale_aesthetic_manual` functions by the `labels =` argument. For examples see [legends cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/#modifying-the-text-of-legend-titles-and-labels). But is not recommended since it gets messy quickly with more variables.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a manual color scheme, with color aesthetics set to desired labels worked for me.

```
source("http://www.openintro.org/stat/data/arbuthnot.R")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = year,y = boys, color="Men"),data=arbuthnot) +
  geom_point(aes(x = year,y = girls, color="Women"),data=arbuthnot,shape = 17) +
  xlab('Year') +
  ylab('Rate') +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=13),
        legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#3399ff', '#ff00ff'))
```

Hope this helps!
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZNp4.png)