# Legend with un-plotted variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have data where each point lays on a spectrum between two centroids. I have generated a color for each point by specifying a color for each centroid, then setting the color of each point as a function of its position between its two centroids. I used this to manually specify colors for each point and plotted the data in the following way:

```
lb.plot.dat <- data.frame('UMAP1' = lb.umap$layout[,1], 'UMAP2' = lb.umap$layout[,2],
                          'sample' = as.factor(substr(colnames(lb.vip), 1, 5)), 
                          'fuzzy.class' = color.vect))
p3 <- ggplot(lb.plot.dat, aes(x = UMAP1, y = UMAP2)) + geom_point(aes(color = color.vect)) +
  ggtitle('Fuzzy Classification') + scale_color_identity() 
p3 + facet_grid(cols = vars(sample)) + theme(legend.) + 
  ggsave(filename = 'ref-samps_bcell-vip-model_fuzzy-class.png', height = 8, width = 16)
```

[image]

(`color.vect` is the aforementioned vector of colors for each point in the plot)

I would like to generate a legend of this plot that gives the color used for each centroid. I have a named vector `class.cols` that contains the colors used for each centroid and is named according to the corresponding class.

Is there a way to transform this vector into a legend for the plot even though it is not explicitly used in the plotting call?

Comment: Probably the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945629/legend-in-ggplot-when-aes-color-and-shape-are-not-specified) is what you want.

Comment: As long as you use `scale_colour_identity()` you will not be able to easily produce a legend as there is no mapping between centroid and colour definitions. Use a factor with one level per centroid instead of `color.vect` and use either `scale_colour_dicrete()` with a suitable palette, or `scale_colour_manual()`if you want to manually control which colour is used for each centroid. A working answer is not possible because your code example cannot be run without you providing the data. You need to provide a minimal or simplified code example and data that demonstrates the problem by itself.

Comment: It would help tremendously if you provided a good reproducible example (reprex): https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html

Answer (score 2):

You can turn on legend drawing in `scale_color_identity()` by setting `guide = "legend"`. You'll have to specify the breaks and labels in the scale function so that the legend correctly states what each color represents, and not just the name of the color.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, color = c("red", "green", "blue"))

# no legend by default
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

```r
# legend turned on
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity(guide = "legend")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>