# Can I modify only the legend of a geom_point() scatter plot (in R / ggplot2) so the entries have particular shapes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60899742) explains how to create a legend that is independent of the plotted data in R and ggplot2. The legend there only uses colors. I would like to also use marker shapes (and readjust the size to a bit larger in order to make them distinguishable more easily).

It was my understanding that the shapes and sizes in a ggplot2 legend could be controlled using `guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = [...])))` (as suggested in, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29308341)).

Unfortunately, I did not succeed. The modified code below unfortunately still results in the same figure as the original (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60899742)) with no impact of shape and marker size specifications in `guides()`. (Note that the question is about the legend and only the legend, not the plot itself. For the plot itself, changing shape and markers is easy ans works nicely.)

Am I doing something wrong? Or am I misunderstanding how legends work (e.g., can I only have one attribute per legend) or how `guide_legend` modifies legends?

```
library(tidyverse)
the_colors <- c("#e6194b", "#3cb44b", "#ffe119", "#0082c8", "#f58231", "#911eb4", "#46f0f0", "#f032e6", 
                "#d2f53c", "#fabebe", "#008080", "#e6beff", "#aa6e28", "#fffac8", "#800000", "#aaffc3", 
                "#808000", "#ffd8b1", "#000080", "#808080", "#ffffff", "#000000")

color_df <- data.frame(the_colors, the_labels = seq_along(the_colors), the_shapes=c(1:22))

the_df <- data.frame("col1"=c(1, 2, 2, 1), "col2"=c(2, 2, 1, 1), "col3"=c(1, 2, 3, 4))

the_plot <- 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data = color_df, aes(x = the_df$col1[[1]], y = the_df$col2[[1]], color = the_colors)) +
    guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = color_df$the_shapes, size=5))) +
    scale_color_identity(guide = 'legend', labels = color_df$the_labels) +
    geom_point(data=the_df, aes(x=col1, y=col2), color=the_colors[[4]], shape=the_df$col3, size=5) 

print(the_plot)
ggsave("test_plot.pdf", plot=the_plot, width=10, height=8)
```

*Note*: I fully realize that this code does not use R and ggplot2 in the way it was intended. This is often met with disapproval. However, I am looking for exactly this feature, and it is is not provided as such in R / ggplot2: Control of the legend independent from the plot and without interfering with the plot.

Comment: You have a `color` legend. Therefore you have to adjust the shapes via `guides(color = ...)`.

Comment: @stefan Indeed, that solves it. Thanks. If you repost this as an answer I will accept it.