# matching of shape, color and legend in bubble plot with subset of variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, bubble-chart

I have some data

```
library(data.table)
wide <- data.table(id=c("A","C","B"), var1=c(1,6,1), var2=c(2,6,5), size1=c(11,12,13), size2=c(10,12,10), flag=c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))
> wide
   id var1 var2 size1 size2  flag
1:  A    1    2    11    10 FALSE
2:  C    6    6    12    12  TRUE
3:  B    1    5    13    10 FALSE
```

which I would like to plot as bubble plots where `id` is ordered by `var2`, and bubbles are as follows:
ID A and B: `var1` is plotted in `size1` and "empty bubbles" and `var2` is plotted in `size2` with "filled" bubbles. 
ID C is flagged because there is only one value (this is why `var1=var2`) and it should have a "filled bubble" of a different color.

I have tried this as follows:

```
cols <- c("v1"="blue", "v2"="red", "flags"="green")
shapes <- c("v1"=16, "v2"=21, "flags"=16)
p1 <- ggplot(data = wide, aes(x = reorder(id,var2))) + scale_size_continuous(range=c(5,15))
p1 <- p1 + geom_point(aes(size=size1, y = var1, color = "v1", shape = "v1")) 
p1 <- p1 + geom_point(aes(size=size2, y = var2, color = "v2", shape = "v2", stroke=1.5))
p1 <- p1 + geom_point(data=subset(wide,flag), aes(size=size2[flag], y=var2[flag], color= "flags", shape="flags"))
p1 <- p1 + scale_color_manual(name = "test", 
                                values = cols,
                                labels = c("v1", "v2", "flags"))
p1 <- p1 + scale_shape_manual(name = "test", 
                              values = shapes,
                              labels = c("v1", "v2", "flags"))
```

which gives (in my theme)

[image: output]

but two questions remain:

1. What happened to the order in the legend? I have followed the recipe of the bottom solution in [Two geom_points add a legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713919/two-geom-points-add-a-legend) but somehow the order does not match.
2. How to get rid of the stroke around the green bubble and why is it there?

Overall, something appears to go wrong in matching shape and color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I admit, it took me a while to understand your slightly convoluted plot. Forgive me, but I have allowed myself to change the way to plot, and make (better?) use of ggplot.

The data shape is less than ideal. ggplot works extremely well with long data. 
It was a bit of a guesswork to reshape your data, and I decided to go the quick and dirty way to simply bind the rows from selected columns.

Now you can see, that you can achieve the new plot with a single call to `geom_point`. The rest is "scale_aesthetic" magic...

In order to combine the shape and color legend, safest is to use `override.aes`. But beware! It does not take named vectors, so the order of the values needs to be in the exact order given by your legend keys - which is usually alphabetic, if you don't have the factor levels defined.

**update** re: request to order x labels

This hugely depends on the actual data structure. if it is originally as you have presented, I'd *first* make `id` a factor with the levels ordered based on your `var2`. Then, do the data shaping.

```r
library(tidyverse)
# data reshape
wide <- data.frame(id=c("C","B","A"), var1=c(1,6,1), var2=c(2,6,5), size1=c(11,12,13), size2=c(10,12,10), flag=c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))
wide <- wide %>% mutate(id = reorder(id, var2))

wide1 <- wide %>% filter(!flag) %>%select(id, var = var1, size = size1)
wide2 <- wide %>%  filter(!flag) %>% select(id, var = var2, size = size2)
wide3 <- wide %>% filter(flag) %>% select(id, var = flag, size = size2) %>%
  mutate(var = 6)
long <- bind_rows(list(v1 = wide1, v2 = wide2, flag = wide3), .id = "var_id") 

# rearrange the vectors for scales aesthetic
cols <- c(flag="green", v1 ="blue", v2="red" )
shapes <- c(flag=16, v1=16, v2 =21 )

ggplot(data = long, aes(x = id, y = var)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=size, shape = var_id, color = var_id), stroke=1.5) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits = c(5,15),breaks = seq(5,15,5)) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "test", values = shapes) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols, guide = FALSE) +
  guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color  = cols)))
```

[image]

P.S. the reason for the red stroke around the green bubble in your plot is that you also plotted the 'var2' behind your flag.

<sup>Created on 2020-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Apologies for the convoluted plot and thanks for digging through it! I had named the data `wide` because the post I linked had already mentioned that `long` data is preferred. However, I wondered then (and still) how to set the order of the categories. Here, they seem to ordered automatically as A, B, C, but how would  I order them by their value on `var` within a particular `var_id`? And how do I get those on `var_id==flag` to be be part of that ordered sequence?

Comment: Also, when applying the method to my real problem, it works unless line  `scale_size_continuous(...)` is added. Then, it returns an warning: `Removed 62 rows containing missing values (geom_point)` and an empty plot. Any idea what this could be? Does this have to do with the re-arrangement of scale aesthetic?

Comment: @bumblebee to the last point - this is most likely because you have sizes outside the scale limit. Remove the limit argument from the scale_size call, or change it

Comment: @bumblebee to the first point - could you specify based on which value you would like to order the IDs? v1 or v2?

Comment: This is likely correct, I might have confuse limits with something else but can only check later. In my post, I ordered by var2 to get the A-B-C order.

Comment: From what i see you suggest ordering them before transforming into long. I have already tried the same but ggplot orders them alphabetically nonetheless.

Comment: @bumblebee I have used the reprex package, so it definitely works. If something doesn't work quite as well as you think - always worth to restart R, remove all predefined objects in the environment, etc. (i.e., start a fresh session).